# WPF : Text loaded in a Wpf textbox is cutted ( not entire )

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to load a text ( as a string ) in a wpf textbox.

```
string str;
string = myFunction();
textBox.Text = str;
```

Here's my XAML :

```
 <TextBox Height="174" Name="textBox1" Width="811" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

My TextBox result is not entire. I trye to write the str in a file on my disk, and the file contains all my data.

Anyone have some idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Pls post a screenshot too, so that we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Remove height and width, and then it should work

Comment: sondegard you're right ! Thanks a lot ! Removed height and width, all is ok :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You've constrained the size of the `TextBox`, so if you have too much text you won't be able to see it all.

Remove the constraints, or specify a `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` value:

```
<TextBox Height="174" Name="textBox1" Width="811" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

[image]